# Whats the easiest way to determine if a user is online? (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, offline

Is there a way I can piggy back sessions to know if the user is online?

I.e: use logs on, I set a $_SESSION variable, user times out- cookie Garbage collector updates the database to update their status as offline.

`EDIT:` I want a solution that does not involve times or dates.  I want something to ride on sessions or something similar.  Guessing if someone is online is not good enough for what I need.

Comment: Tracking based upon "last_activity_time" or tracking based upon an expired session isn't going to really matter with regards to accurately telling you how many users are "online." The major difference is you can implement the first method in about 5 minutes. The latter method would require you to constantly be checking all sessions (for all users...ouch) and processing their values - yuck.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to clearly know if the user is connected to the site.

Comment: @Mike, check out my appended solution.

Comment: If my understanding is correct. A online user means, his session is persisting in the server. So if we keep the session in a database table rather than in a file, we can easily count right?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Don't bother with figuring out the differences between time zones—that's not necessary.

Whenever the user accesses a page, set/update a *lastActiveTime* field in their record of the *Users* table. Then, do a [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) for all users having a *lastActiveTime* within the last 5 minutes. Anything more than this, and they can be considered "offline."

If you use your server-time, via the [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function in MySQL, you'll avoid the need to deal with time zones. This is the standard way of tracking how many users are presently online (meaning, active within the last *x* minutes).

#### Constantly Updated

If you would like to know they are still active (even when they're not jumping from page to page), you could include a bit of JavaScript to ping your server every 60 seconds. It'll work the same way as my original suggestion, but it will update your records without requiring users to be frantically browsing your site at least once every five minutes.

*Original 2009 Code*

```
var stillAlive = setInterval(function () {
    /* XHR back to server
       Example uses jQuery */
    $.get("stillAlive.php");
}, 60000);
```

*Updated 2022 Code*

We can use [*fetch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) and [*promises*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) today to more precisely issue these calls. Fetch will replace our earlier XHR approach using jQuery. Fetch returns a Promise, which we'll use (via the `await` keyword) to defer timing of our next call. Once the call to `stillAlive.php` is complete, and a response has been retrieved, we'll setup the next *ping* for 60 seconds later.

```js
(async function ping () {
    // Asynchronously call stillAlive.php
    await fetch( "stillAlive.php" );
    // Issue this call again in 60 seconds
    setTimeout( ping, 60_000 );
}());
```

Comment: I've been wandering through an ocean of websites with such a similar problem, and you're the first person to give a satisfying answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you put an index on the timestamp in DB ?

Comment: Another simple answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser#answer-24402832

Comment: I am thinking of using this method on my own site but where the commented section /* XHR back to server Example uses jQuery */ has me a little confused, does this just execute a php script which updates the last time seen by the user in the database every 60 seconds? I find no information about what goes in this function anywhere.

Comment: I don't think `setInterval()` is suitable for any fetch actions, given that the fetch timing is highly unpredictable. It's more reasonable to do `setTimeout()` indefinitely, after fetching is complete.

Comment: @RoboRobok Good call. While I don't think precise timing matters in this example, it is definitely cleaner to wait until after the fetch is complete before you schedule the next ping. I've added some updated 2022 code for future readers :)

Comment: Thanks! I agree that in this case it's not that much of a difference, but it may lead to less server load and a bit more correct indication of whether someone's online or not. I'm nitpicking a little :]

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for (after the clarification) is, by definition, impossible.  HTTP is a connectionless protocol, so as soon as a user has hit a page and all the content comes back from the server to the user's browser, there is no connection between the two.  Someone is "online" with your website for less than a second.

One thing you *could* do is to have JavaScript on your web page make AJAX requests back to your server on a regular basis which includes identifying information, and a different AJAX request when the user leaves the page, using **window.onbeforeunload**.

Comment: this browser event 'onbeforeunload' is so great, but it doesn't work when user's internet connection is lost and he closes browser tabs

Answer (score 5):

My way may not be the best way but since my site and userbase is all in mysql DB, when a user logins into my site,

1. I update the user table to say they
   are online
2. Insert them into an Online table
3. Then I set a session with the
   current time

Then on every page load I check for the online time session, if it exist, I check to see how old it is, if it is less then 5 minutes old, I do nothing, if it is older then 5 minutes, then I update the session time again with current time and also update the online users table with the time

Then I have a cron job that runs every 10 - 15 minutes that deletes any uses from online table and marks there user table as offline if there online time has updated within X amount of minutes

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your "is the person online" comparison logic isn't taking into account the timezones.  If you are dealing with timezones in this manner, I strongly recommend that you store all your times in GMT, and convert them to local time for your users right before you display them.  This will make any comparison operations very simple.

There's a nice SO thread about timezones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975/handling-timezones-in-storage).

Comment: +1 for GMT. Second best is using Server Time. But if you ever need to move the server across timezones, that screws up all your historical data. Far better to store datetimes in GMT. Server Time also works on an internal database only accessed from a single location (like an office). But even offices can move.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would advise is to store this kind of information in memory with for example memcached or mysql heap or redis. Because otherwise the database will be hit a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Store the time-zone in the table, and use it in a calculation to find that users local time in comparison to the local time of the user viewing the page.

**Edit:**

Better yet, store all times as the server time, and base all calculations relative only to the server time.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your situation, it may be better for you to create a separate table "whose-online" with the columns: "ip" and "last-updated-time" and query/update this table every time a user loads a page.

**On page load queries may include**:

1. Update/insert "whose-online" table for current user based on ip.
2. Delete "expired" rows (can also be done periodically using cronjob).
3. Count "active" users.

**Benefits of using this technique**:

1. If a user is not logged in, he/she is still being counted/tracked.
2. Depends on the amount of users you have, querying this table may be quicker.

Note: If you use this you should want to take into consideration that any pageview will create a row in your table so based on useragent you can disregard bots or only count the popular ones (Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have implemented for this is to, on every page load by an authenticated user, set/reset a memcache var such as "user_{userid}*isonline" => true and expire it in 5 minutes. Then check if the var is in the cache when I access the user's info.  Depending on the size of your user base, if you want to get a list of everyone online, you could use a memcache getmulti call with an array of "user*{userid}_isonline" keys for all of your users.

of course, this really depends on how often a user will change pages on your site... to get a more accurate representation of the users online, you could implement an ajax xmlhttprequest call on your page running at a small interval (30 seconds or so) that resets the memcache var, and have the memcache var expire in less time (1 minute to account for possible browser issues).  This is not COMPLETELY accurate, but as http does not have a persistent connection to the server, you are pretty limited on what you can do.

IF you require an up to the second representation of who is online, you could maybe have a flash app loaded in your page that connects to a jabber server, then just check if that particular user is logged in on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way on how to get the difference between two dates from a database in minutes, then check for the difference and set the online/offline status.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

foreach($result as $user){
    // date from the database
    $dbLastActivity = date("d-m-Y h:i:s a", strtotime($user['lastOnline']));
    // date now
    $now = date("d-m-Y h:i:s a", $date);

    // calculate the difference
    $difference = strtotime($now) - strtotime($dbLastActivity);
    $difference_in_minutes = $difference / 60;

    // check if difference is greater than five minutes
    if($difference_in_minutes < 5){
        // set online status
        $updateStatus = 'UPDATE Users SET Status="online" WHERE lastOnline="'.$user['lastOnline'].'"';
    } else {
        // set offline status
        $updateStatus = 'UPDATE Users SET Status="offline" WHERE lastOnline="'.$user['lastOnline'].'"';
    }

    // check if mysqli query was successful
    if (!$mysqli->query($updateStatus)){
        printf("Error Message %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you're doing this with 20 lines PHP instead of 1 line of SQL because....reasons?

Comment: Curious to see this code in 1 line :) show it to me.. i said what i did.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE last_active >= (NOW() - interval '5 minutes')`

Comment: Or for the whole shebang... sql: `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE last_active >= (NOW() - interval '5 minutes')` set_active.php: `pg_query_params($conn, "UPDATE Users SET last_active=NOW() WHERE user_id=$1", [$_GET['user_id']]`);` heartbeat.js: `setInterval(() => { fetch('last_active.php?user_id=' + userID }, 60000)`

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `onunload` tag... On the body 
More information here (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)

This way you don't have to wait 4 -5 minutes for the user to get offline.

But you should still use the ajax update method in-case the user's browser crashes...

**Edit:**
As [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) pointed out in the comments you may not be able to send out requests but there is a way you can do it...
Explained in more detail in [this Article](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded#window-onunload).
So basically they are using the [sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)
Here is an Example

```js
window.addEventListener("unload", function logData() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
});
```

**NOTE:** Although it should be kept in mind that this should not be the only method you should depend upon, and should implement for redundancy...

Comment: Sending a message to the server in onunload is, IIRC, impossible (because the request gets canceled as the page unloads). It also wouldn't work if the user stopped being online because they turned their computer off, went into a tunnel with no mobile signal, etc.

Comment: @Quentin We can still use `sendBeacon()` as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

Comment: No if the user stopped being online because they turned their computer off, went into a tunnel with no mobile signal, etc