# PHP - Session destroy after closing browser

Tags: php, session, cookies

Though this question has multiple duplicates i could not find proper solution for me.
Need Some help.

I have used `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  0);` in my configuration file.

But it is not helping me to destroy session on browser close.

Application current flow:

1) In authentication page if user is valid, generate new session identifier using `session_regenerate_id(true);`

2) Control goes to welcome.php where i start new session using `session_start();`

3) in logout page code is

```
      $_SESSION = array();
      if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
      );
     }
    // Finally, destroy the session.
    session_destroy();
```

Comment: Please elaborate more. What actually do you mean by "destroy session"?

Comment: i want to close existing session if user close browser. If user reopen browser i want to send him login page again.

Comment: what "close existing session" means?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do this, you can however delete the session on start up.

Comment: A browser closing is never the best way to destroy a cookie session because the webserver never knows when the browser is closed. The browser doesn't send any notification that it is closing to the server so the server can't send the commamd to delete the cookie because the browser has closed.

Comment: Hint, uncheck the *remember me* option when logging in. ;p

Comment: @Big Chris Exactly. But is there any way to handle this situation?

Comment: @Shri How are you currently checking if the session valid? Can you post the code you have?

Comment: just let the users log-in every time they visit your startpage.

Comment: @Manju Currently i am using session id to check valid session along with some values i have store in session

Comment: @Shri
1. It is better if you share session checking code from login and logout pages
2. How are you testing it to make sure it works?

Comment: if you want that the user must be logged in after closing the browser, visit : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31422784/4380588

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to close the session is: if there is no response for that session after particular interval of time. then close. Please see this post and I hope it will resolve the issue. **"[How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)"**

Answer (score 10):

This might help you,

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

Your session cookie will be destroyed... so your session will be good until the browser is open. please view http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php this may help you.

Comment: this should be the top answer

Answer (score 9):

Use a keep alive.

On login:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_action'] = time();
```

An ajax call every few (eg 20) seconds:

```
windows.setInterval(keepAliveCall, 20000);
```

Server side keepalive.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_action'] = time();
```

On every other action:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['last_action'] < time() - 30 /* be a little tolerant here */) {
  // destroy the session and quit
}
```

Comment: This is a solution for the small man. why? because if you change the session it needs to be rewritten at the end of the script. If you have a big website, that is a lot of I/O just to auto logoff users.

Comment: @Umigo: You do not need to use files as session storage. PHP provides for example Memcache as alternative.

Comment: The best and the most simple answer on how to check if a user is online or offline (y)

Comment: @colburton Even when using Memcache; it's still I/O and, with enough users, will cause problems nonetheless. Also it, potentially, causes a lot more requests that _also_ need to be handled by the webserver(s) which _also_ costs resources (however small you may be able to get them, it won't be zero). I'd rather reevaluate why one would want to destroy sessions in such a hurry than harm the possibility to scale or cause 'unnecessary' load on machines.

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to do this, but the server can't detect when de browser gets closed so destroying it then is hard.

- timeout session.

Either create a new session with the current time or add a time variable to the current session. and then check it when you start up or perform an action to see if the session has to be removed.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
//if 100 seconds have passed since creating session delete it.
if(time() - $_SESSION["timeout"] > 100){ 
    unset($_SESSION["timeout"];
}
```

- ajax

Make javascript perform an ajax call that will delete the session, with `onbeforeunload()` a javascript function that calls a final action when the user leaves the page. For some reason this doesnt always work though.

- delete it on startup.

If you always want the user to see the login page on startup after the page has been closed you can just delete the session on startup.

```
<? php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["session"]);
```

and there probably are some more.

Answer (score 2):

There's one more "hack" by using HTTP Referer (we asume that browser window was closed current referer's domain name and curent page's domain name do not match):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['somevariable'] = 'somevalue';

if(parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], PHP_URL_HOST) != $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]){
    session_destroy();
}
```

This also has some drawbacks, but it helped me few times.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using JavaScript by triggering an ajax request to server to destroy the session on onbeforeunload event fired when we closes the browse tab or window or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to destroy the session:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['sessionvariable']);
    header("Location:index.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: This is fine if user clicks Logout. I think Shri is wanting to make sure session gets destroyed whenever user closes the browser.

Comment: session automatically gets destroyed on closing the browser

Comment: Read the question first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the session id on each log in, make sure to use session_regenerate_id(true) during the log in process.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you close your browser your session is lost.

session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser.

session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 176400);  // for 48 hours
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 176400);  // for 48 hours
session_start();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are confused what to do, just refer to the manual of **session_destroy()** function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

There you can find some more features of session_destroy().