# how to close the session and redirect to index page when browser in closed

Tags: php, session

I want to clear the session variables when the tab is closed but I could not find any solutions so far. here user without login they will enter the url dashboard.php means it will redirect to index.php, this condition is working fine, now user successfully login means it will go to dashboard.php page after that user close this tab and again they will enter dashboard.php page means i want to redirect the page in index.php, how can do this

```
<?php
  session_start();
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
  include('dbconfig.php');
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $password=md5($password);
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,username,email,password,is_user_type FROM login WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
  list($id,$username,$email,$pwd,$is_user_type)=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
  if($pwd==$password){
  $_SESSION['username']=$username;
  $_SESSION['email']=$email;
  $_SESSION['is_user_type']=$is_user_type;
  $_SESSION['current'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   header("Location:dashboard.php");
  }
  else{
      echo "error";
     }
    ?>

dashboard.php
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && empty($_SESSION['email'])) {
  header("Location:index.php");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['current'])) {
 if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != $_SESSION['current']) {
    session_destroy();
 }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your xyz.php file set a unique variable in the $_SESSION array which will act as a mark that the user has been on this page

```
$_SESSION['previous'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Then, add the following code on all pages, before any output to check if the user is coming from xyz.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['previous'])) {
   if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != $_SESSION['previous']) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['previous']);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr @ Pravin Vavadiya

Comment: please check my updated code,successfully logged means it will go to dashboard.php page.then i refresh the page means again it will come to login page,should not come like this

Comment: "add the following code on all pages, before any output to check if the user is coming from xyz.php".. in your dashboard.php first add this code after check email seesion....

Answer (score 0):

To remove particular session data , try this

```
  if($_SESSION[sessionvaribale] )
  {
   unset($_SESSION[sessionvaribale]);
   }
```

To destroy all session data - try `session_destroy()`

Its already discussed by Stackoverflow

Refer [Session destroy when logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser)