# Session destroy in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

```
I want login page whenever Yii2 project open in browser.
```

> Let me know what steps do we need to follow to destroy session when system will have power off.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser

Comment: Thanks Yasin for help, but in your link it shows session destroy after time interval. I want destroy session in close browser. Please reply regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `enableAutoLogin` to `false` in your config file. This setting is false by default but the basic and advanced Yii2 template both set this value to true.

When it is false the cookie that will be created for the login will **not** be used to authenticate the user when 'first' coming on the page and so the login page will be displayed.

The docs:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$enableAutoLogin-detail