# Browser cookie: How to destroy session storage cookie after user closes the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session-cookies, session-storage

We just realized a problem that the session storage and cookies are remembered in chrome/firefox if user has selected continue where I left off.

We want to destroy session storage and session cookies as this is very critical for us. How could we do this even if user has continue where left off setting ON?

One temporary solution could be to not make it session level but expire after sometime. Any other better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Session destroy after closing browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser)

Comment: You could combine onunload and [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) to tell your server when it should close the session.

Comment: Didn't get you. Could you please elaborate?