# Session is destroy after close navigator?

Tags: php

i have a php script that is using

```
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
```

for declare the session, and work fine, but if you close the navigator the session is removed, and i cant see why, my php.ini is this [php.ini](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheSunMan/4008090/raw/8fa040681e858432c68e60024d588a20f67817bf/php.ini%2520Default)

Comment: What does the `$_SESSION["username"]` prints after you close the navigator? Btw you mean after closing the browser?

Comment: yea, if u close the tab the and open a new one the session still but, if u close the tab and browser the session is gone, $_SESSION["username"]  is a input username post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Session destroy after closing browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser)

Answer (score 0):

This is because sessions are not permanent. A session is tied to the browser you have open. Once you close it, the session is gone.

If you want to keep some information permanently. You will want to use a database and store the information there.

Comment: the session should still, you can try anything like facebooks sessions, and the input username is with sql

Comment: @atra those are not sessions. Cookies store data in the browser if it gets closed. That is what most sites use for login data.

Comment: so i should use cookies for store sessions ?

Comment: @atra if you want to simply have the browser remember a person's login details so they don't have to put in their username/password each time they visit your site, then yes, use Cookies.

Comment: so  ex facebook use cookies for store theirs sessions ?

Comment: @atra First off, sessions and cookies are different things. But for what you are asking, yes Facebook uses cookies.

Comment: okey ty, i dont have exxpereicen using cookies i will check it

Answer (score 0):

Session is automatically destroyed after you close browser, for permanent storage use a database(mysql)

Comment: the login username is stored on sql

Comment: When you close browser and open it ...are you logged in? Or logged out?

Comment: if i close the tab but not the broswer logged, if i close all the brrowse logged out

Comment: Yeah, so once logged out session variable gets destroyed , you will need to again login to make it get printed....Use cookie so that you dont logout even after closing browser.

Comment: yea i will use cookies ty! :D, bbtw i read that cookies are vulnerable ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach read it