# How to hide adsense ads to visitors coming from specific campaign?

Tags: php, hide, adsense, utm

**How to hide adsense ads to visitors coming from specific campaign?**

Until now, I've found the way to hide ads when the URL contains the word "share"

For example:

it won't show the adsense ad if the landing page of my campaign is:

```
https://example.com/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=share
```

I use the following code to do that:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'share') !== false) {
    return false;
} else { ?>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000000000"
     data-ad-slot="0000000000"
     data-ad-format="link"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is, when the visitor goes to another page within my website, the utm parameter is removed from the URL, and adsense ad show up again.

I need your help to make sure any visitor coming from campaign

`?utm_source=social&utm_medium=share` don't see any adsense ad, no matter if the visitor navigate my entire website, the visitor should not see the adsense ad.

If you know another workaround for this problem, something more simple, please share it. I will forget the code above and use yours.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Regards

Comment: You want to read the $_GET variables and store them in a session on all your pages, perhaps just include a file that does this at the top of all your pages so you don't have to re write it. Also within that import, if there are no get variables set, check the session

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a file on top of all your pages that checks for those parameters and stores them in a session, try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['utm_source'])) {
    $_SESSION['utm_source'] = $_GET['utm_source'];
}
if (isset($_GET['utm_medium'])) {
    $_SESSION['utm_medium'] = $_GET['utm_medium'];
}
if (
    (isset($_SESSION['utm_source']) && $_SESSION['utm_source'] == 'social') &&
    (isset($_SESSION['utm_medium']) && $_SESSION['utm_medium'] == 'share'))
{
    // DON'T SHOW ADS
} else {
    // SHOW ADS
}
```

Comment: This will overwrite the variables on each page load. It needs to see if the session variables exist first.

Comment: @aynber Yes, I spotted that as soon as I posted it, I have revised it, if you could please amend your downvote it would be appreciated.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, I just commented. And that still looks extremely convoluted.

Comment: @aynber Convoluted how?

Comment: Well, that's not how ternaries work. A ternary will return a value based on the T/F of the left expression. Actually setting a value inside of the true value may not work. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @aynber It worked on my machine but yes, you are correct, it is an incorrect use of ternarys, I have edited.

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 it wasn't my downvote either, it must be a hater somewhere.
I'm considering to try your solution, because is the only answer I have until now.
Btw, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sshcli If this project is a dynamic website with a lot of backend interaction, I politely suggest looking into PHP frameworks such as Laravel, it is great even for static websites

Comment: Thanks @iJamesPHP2 your solution works! 
I have upvoted for your answer. 
Now I only need to find the way to delete the session when the visitor closes the browser. 
Because if the same visitor return to the website directly (Not via social share campaign), the visitor will not see any ads, and I want to show ads always, except when coming from campaign social share.

Comment: @sshcli Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402047/php-session-destroy-after-closing-browser/24402832

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 very useful. My problem is solved now. Thanks a lot ! See you around