# How do I set the user status (online/offline) in a Yii-2 application

Tags: php, yii2

For this I wrote a function in the Gii generated User model which sets the 'status' field of the corresponding user table as follows

```
public function setStatus()
    {
     if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
     $this->status = 1;
     }
     else {
         $this->status = 0;
     }
    }
```

Now in my Controller :

```
public function actionLogout()
    {
        $usr = new \frontend\models\User;
        $usr->setStatus();

        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();

    }
```

But Yii throws an error:

> Cannot redeclare frontend\models\User::tableName();

I tried to echo all the autoloaded classes but the class is not autoloaded. How do I go about this?

Comment: Have you create  a new User class using Gii?

Comment: Please show your frontend\model\User, you should have a function like this: `public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }`

Comment: Obviously it has, because gii generates it automatically.

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes, I mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your error, check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953857/getting-a-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-function-error).

Most likely you defined it twice in this class, and you don't use IDE because majority of them highlight this kind of errors.

As for status - this doesn't make sense. Using `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` check is enough for determing if user is logged or guest. But this is not suitable for determing if user is online / offline.

As for this problem, there are similar questions asked before, check for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051895/whats-the-easiest-way-to-determine-is-a-user-in-online-php-mysql).

And finally, don't use hardcoded statuses, declare them as constants in model instead:

```
const STATUS_OFFLINE = 1;
const STATUS_ONLINE = 2;
```

Usage: `self::STATUS_OFFLINE` (inside of class where it's declared) or `User::STATUS_OFFLINE` (don't forget to include namespace in use section).

**Update:** Considering that user is online only because user is logged in seems not be right. But if need only calculating who is online / offline among logged in users, why you need statuses if there are only two possible options? Use `is_online` boolean column instead.

Comment: I mentioned constants usage because using numbers is a bad practice.