# How do chats detect a user is online or offline

Tags: chat, detection

Hi,

I am creating a web chat from scratch and I came across this issue. How can I detect a user is still online (this meaning they still have the chat window/tab open). I have seen chats that handle this very efficiently but I dont even know what language are they using to accomplish this. Any hints please? My chat is entirely html, php and javascript only by the way.

Thank you.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051895/whats-the-easiest-way-to-determine-if-a-user-is-online-php-mysql) help answer your question?